# WPF ListBox select All items using xaml only

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

Can I select all items in WPF Listbox through XAML only?

I followed this question as well [WPF Listbox and Select All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030276/wpf-listbox-and-select-all) but it's not working.
My XAML code as follows:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll" Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="A" />
    </ListBox.InputBindings>
    <ListBox.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll"  />
    </ListBox.CommandBindings>
    <ListBoxItem>List Item 1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>List Item 2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>List Item 3</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>List Item 4</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>List Item 5</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Is Select all possible through XAMl only?

Comment: What does *XAML only* means for you because you are using a `Command`?

Comment: i mean without any code behind code in c#/vb. i can remove command binding.

Comment: I have to use this XAML view in poweshell. so code behind won't work in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `ListBox` has its own `SelectAllCommand` but it is private so you can't bind to it. It doesn't handle the `ApplicationCommands.SelectAll` command for you. You need to do this yourself by handling the `Executed` event of the `CommandBinding`:

```
private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox.SelectAll();
}
```

XAML is a markup language and not a programming language.